# Can not run jmeter.bat file

Tags: jmeter

I get the below error when I run the jmeter.bat file. Could someone help me with this? Thank you..!

- C:\Users\PrabMish\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.3\bin>jmeter.bat
  java.lang.Throwable: Could not access
  C:\Users\PrabMish\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.3\lib\ext at
  org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.(NewDriver.java:104)
  java.lang.Throwable: Could not access
  C:\Users\PrabMish\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.3\lib\junit at
  org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.(NewDriver.java:104)
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jmeter.JMeter at
  java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at
  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at
  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at
  org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:249) JMeter home
  directory was detected as:
  C:\Users\PrabMish\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.3

---

Comment: I am not directly involved with this batch file, someone else might help. But as a community member I can suggest altering the question such that it has what you are trying to achieve, what command was run and it's response. Use code blocks

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it indicates an issue with your JMeter installation, i.e.

1. Make sure to download the **binary**, not the source

   [image]
2. Make sure to download it fully (i.e. check sha512 or pgp of the downloaded archive)

   [image]

   for JMeter 5.3 it should be equal to what you see at https://downloads.apache.org/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.3.zip.sha512 URL
3. Make sure to have JDK or server JRE of version not less than 8 for JMeter 5.3, you can get it i.e. from [OpenJDK project page](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/)
4. `java.exe` should be on your operating system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))
5. If you have problems with `jmeter.bat` script you can always launch JMeter as:

   ```
   java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar
   ```

   from the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation

More information:

- [Apache JMeter -> Getting Started -> Installation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#install)
- [How to Get Started With JMeter: Installation & Test Plans](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans)

Comment: Thank you.. I could resolve the problem after reinstalled again