# Unable to launch the JMeter on Windows either jmeter bat file nor jar file

Tags: jmeter

I tried  Jmetre.bat, java -jar ApacheJmeter.jar from the CMD as well as clicking the jmeter.bat file from the folder, but no luck getting the below error.

See the below screen shots for the Jmeter env variable set up. It used to work till  V5.4.2

```html
C:\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\bin>jmeter.bat
java.lang.Throwable: Could not access C:\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\lib
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit>(NewDriver.java:106)
java.lang.Throwable: Could not access C:\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\lib\ext
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit>(NewDriver.java:106)
java.lang.Throwable: Could not access C:\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\lib\junit
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit>(NewDriver.java:106)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jmeter.JMeter
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:251)
JMeter home directory was detected as: C:\apache-jmeter-5.4.3

C:\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\bin>java -jar ApacheJmeter.jar
java.lang.Throwable: Could not access C:\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\lib
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit>(NewDriver.java:106)
java.lang.Throwable: Could not access C:\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\lib\ext
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit>(NewDriver.java:106)
java.lang.Throwable: Could not access C:\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\lib\junit
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit>(NewDriver.java:106)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jmeter.JMeter
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:251)
JMeter home directory was detected as: C:\apache-jmeter-5.4.3
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the steps listed in this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65086266/can-not-run-jmeter-bat-file

Comment: @DylanLacey  Thanks you! After Reinstallation it worked!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your JMeter installation broken somehow, I would suggest:

1. Re-downloading the latest stable version from [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page. Make sure to choose one of archives under **Binaries** and not to download source code distribution by accident.
2. [Verifying the downloaded archive checksum](https://www.apache.org/info/verification.html) - it must be the same with the one `sha512` next to the download link
3. Just in case move your [JDK installation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/) to a folder which doesn't contain spaces and/or special characters

More information: [Get Started With JMeter: Installation & Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans)